# Add A column that gives a NO or Yes Based on Date [Borrowed Date]

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. Basically what I want is a column that will appear beside [Borrowed Date]
2. This column will be called Status it will have two values
3. The values will depend on a condition that if the Date Today will be 3 days greater than [Borrowed Date] then the Status column = Overdue, Else it should show Not Overdue

Here is my code.

```
SELECT dbo.borrowing.[book_id], 
       dbo.bookregistration.[book_title], 
       dbo.bookregistration.[book_category], 
       dbo.bookregistration.[book_type], 
       dbo.bookregistration.edition, 
       dbo.borrowing.[borrowed_date], 
       dbo.borrowing.[adm_no] 
FROM   dbo.bookregistration 
INNER JOIN dbo.borrowing ON dbo.bookregistration.[book_id] = dbo.borrowing.[book_id]
```

Comment: Which database you are using is important as data methods are different in different databases.

Comment: im Using Ms Sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

```
SELECT dbo.Borrowing.[Book_ID], dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_Title]
    , dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_Category], dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_Type]
    , dbo.BookRegistration.Edition, dbo.Borrowing.[Borrowed_Date] AS [Borrowed_Date]
    , case when DATEADD(DD,3,[Borrowed_Date]) > GETDATE() THEN 'Not Overdue' ELSE 'Overdue' END AS Status
    , dbo.Borrowing.[Adm_NO]
FROM dbo.BookRegistration
INNER JOIN dbo.Borrowing ON dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_ID] = dbo.Borrowing.[Book_ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. **First** we will make it shorter using `alias`, **2nd** using `select case`

**Here's your complete query.**

```
SELECT t2.[Book_ID]
    , t1.[Book_Title]
    , t1.[Book_Category]
    , t1.[Book_Type]
    , t1.Edition
    , case when t2.[Borrowed_Date] < getdate() - 3 then 'OverDue' else 'Not Overdue' end as [Status]
    , t2.[Adm_NO]
FROM  dbo.BookRegistration t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.Borrowing t2 ON t1.[Book_ID] = t2.[Book_ID]
```

Comment: you can use datediff() function to get the difference between 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_ADD and CASE statement to achieve your requirement as below-

```
SELECT        
    CASE 
        WHEN DATE_ADD([Borrowed Date], INTERVAL 3 DAY) > NOW() THEN 'Not Overdue'
        ELSE 'Overdue'
    END Status
FROM dbo.BookRegistration
INNER JOIN dbo.Borrowing 
    ON dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_ID] = dbo.Borrowing.[Book_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   dbo.Borrowing.[Book_ID],
   dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_Title],
   dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_Category],
   dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_Type],
   dbo.BookRegistration.Edition,
   dbo.Borrowing.[Borrowed_Date],
   dbo.Borrowing.[Adm_NO],
   Case
      when
         DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), Borrowed_Date) = 3 
      then
         'OVERDUE' 
      ELSE
         'NOT OVERDUE' 
   END
   AS STATUS 
FROM
   dbo.BookRegistration 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Borrowing 
      ON dbo.BookRegistration.[Book_ID] = dbo.Borrowing.[Book_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT
      B.[Book_ID]
      , BR.[Book_Title]
      , BR.[Book_Category]
      , BR.[Book_Type]
      , BR.Edition
      , CASE WHEN DATE_ADD([B.Borrowed_Date], INTERVAL 3 DAY) > GetDate() THEN 'Not Overdue' ELSE 'Overdue' END Status
      , BR.[Adm_NO]   
 FROM dbo.BookRegistration BR
 INNER JOIN dbo.Borrowing B ON BR.[Book_ID] = B.[Book_ID]
```